# How to use suggestion with extra fields on azure search

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using a tutorial provided by microsoft regarding azure search:
the uri: https://victorious-beach-0ab88b51e.azurestaticapps.net/
code source : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-javascript-samples/tree/master/search-website

when you look for a book for example, the suggestion list looks like this :
[image]

the bihavouir that I'm looking for is, instead of having just the author and the title, I need to display the type of the filed Imean, if it is an author it should be displayed like  this :

> J. Daniels (author)

if it is a title it should be displayed like  this :

> J is for Judgment(Kinsey Millhone #10) (title)

is it possible to do that with azure search ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Search will only return verbatim content in your search index, and it returns the whole field (for example, if your query has $select=author-name, title, description, then the search results will include the full content of all three fields in each result). To get the outcome you want, you'd need to have a field that can return "J. Daniels (author)" or write client code that concatenates and formats the result. I've seen recommendations for using Azure Data Factory for data prep, but I haven't tried it myself so it's just a suggestion.